# How to change the time interval in a Gantt chart using BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, report, birt, gantt-chart

I am using BIRT with Eclipse to create a report that has a Gantt chart displaying employee tasks.

My data source has the following structure:

1. TaskName (String)
2. TaskStart (DateTime)
3. TaskEnd. (DateTime)

I want to add some parameters (something like year/month/week/day) so that the time interval (the horizontal axis) changes and displays a more "zoomed-in" or "zoomed-out" view.
I suppose i should make 4 DataSet parameters and 4 Report parameters and somehow link them.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: check out our open source project for Project Management in Eclipse http://www.lowcoupling.com/mdpm http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ZMPvgHUv5f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the BIRT Help menu and search for "Parameter"

You should find "How to create a basic report parameter" which will help you create report parameters.  The report will zoom in or out to the data set described by the paramters

```
SELECT *

FROM source

WHERE date >= ?
AND date <= ?
```